# String hex to Dec Int/converting positive to negative

Tags: java, string, hex, decimal

i´m a programming newbie so please be nice :)
I just wrote a program which convert a hex String to dec int. I´ve testet it with "negative" hex, and some values are right and some are wrong. I can´t really resolve the issue with the wrong output.

here´s my code:

```
    String abc = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    String hexString = "-ffad";
    int decResult = 0;
    //int endRes = 0;

    hexString = hexString.toUpperCase();

    for(int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i++)
    {
        if(hexString.contains("-"))
        {
            hexString = hexString.replace("-", "");
            char res = hexString.charAt(i);
            int d = abc.indexOf(res);
            decResult = (16*decResult + d)*(-1);
        }
        else
            {
                char res = hexString.charAt(i);
                int d = abc.indexOf(res);
                decResult = ((16*decResult) + d)*1;
            }
    }
    System.out.println(decResult);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are doing this

```
if(hexString.contains("-"))
```

for EVERY char in the **hexString** string then the final sign of the convertion will be calculated as

- negative if **hexString.length()** is odd,
- positive otherwise.

a working solution improved can be:

```
    hexString = hexString.toUpperCase();
    int sign = hexString.charAt(0) == '-' ? -1 : 1;
    hexString = hexString.replace("-", "");
    decResult = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16) * sign;
    System.out.println(decResult);
```

Comment: `hexString.replace("-", "")` still is an operation unnecessarily processing all characters (and causing certain malformed input to stay unnoticed). It rather should be `if(sign) hexString = hexString.substring(1);`. But, of course, if you’re going to use `Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16)` anyway, neither, the conversion to uppercase nor the special handling of the minus, makes any sense as `Integer.parseInt("-ffad", 16)` will already do the job.